# Exclude certain matches using NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am following http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial and using the  playground file below:

http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/iRegex-Playground-Xcode-6.3.zip

to help find matches , but I need to be able to exclude certain results .

Basically I am looking at the following pattern:

```
let thenotClasses = "*121:32,  Malachi 22:66 , 32:434, 16:111 , 17:11 , John 13:14, Verse 41:29, Great 71:21"

listMatches("\\d\\d?\\d?:\\d\\d?\\d?", inString: thenotClasses)
```

I get all the number:number matches , however, what I really want to do is to also tell it to exclude any matches  prefixed with '*' or matches which are preceded by the word "Malachi " or "John " but include the rest

So in this case I want the matches to return:

```
[32:434, 16:111 , 17:11 , 41:29  and 71:21]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, God willing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RegEx pattern that invalidates a match when preceded by certain words are hard to write, mostly because the regex engine is greedy so it can start with the next digit.

If you use a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!\*|Malachi |John )(\d+:\d+)
```

Which means "match digits not preceded by `*`, `Malachi` or `John`" the match will just begin from the next digit. In `Malachi 22:66` for example, it will capture `2:66`.

The most common pitfalls I've seen with Regex usage is to delegate everything to the regex engine. It is powerful indeed but you forgot you also have vastly more flexible programming language that calls the regex.

Here's an idea that mixes the two together: capture any `number:number` and check what goes before it. Exclude the match if it is preceded by `*` or `Malachi` or `John`.

Pattern:

```
(\*|Malachi |John )?(\d+:\d+)

(\*|Malachi |John ) - match a *, Malachi or John and put it into capture group 1
?                   - make the first capture group optional
(\d+:\d+)           - match the verse and put it into capture group 2
```

Code:

```
let str = "*121:32,  Malachi 22:66 , 32:434, 16:111 , 17:11 , John 13:14, Verse 41:29, Great 71:21"
let s = str as NSString  // NSString is easier to work with Regex

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\*|Malachi |John )?(\\d+:\\d+)", options: [])
var verses = [String]()

regex.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count)) { result, flags, stop in
   // Check that the first capture group is not found. Otherwise, return
    guard let result = result where result.rangeAtIndex(1).location == NSNotFound else {
        return
    }

    // When the first capture group is not found, add the second capture, group
    // i.e. the verse number, to the result list
    verses.append(s.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(2)))
}

print(verses)
```